# setup.py in python: how to install subpackages?

Tags: python, setup.py

Consider the following package structure:

```
src/
   /__init__.py
   bar.py
   /foo
       /__init__.py
       foobar.py
```

I want to write a setup.py such that if I do:

```
pip install -e .
```

from the root directory, all the following will work:

```
import src
import src.foo
import foo
```

I am able to achieve the first two easily using e.g. find_namespace_packages, but I have tried various combos of find_namespace_packages(), find_packages(), package_dir, to also be able to import the subpackage foo without specifying the prefix (i.e. src.foo) without success. How do I do this?

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can't with the way you structure/package your codes. Python will look in `src` and each `__init__.py` allows for it to be indexed and thus it's consider part of the same package. Plus, there are potential namespace conflicts. What if instead of `foo` you had `csv`? That would break the default `csv` library for python. By specifying `src.foo` it's explicit where `foo` is defined.

Comment: What you really should consider is having `foo` as a separate repo that is PyPI package, then add it in your requirements.txt and from there in `src/__init__.py` do `import foo`. Then `src.foo` would be available.

Comment: @astrochun I see your point. It's just that I am dealing with a codebase where there's a bunch of subpackages with modules and they sometimes import using src.foo, and sometimes just using foo. I think it's because the code was developed by hacking on the pythonpath so that all submodules are accessible.

Comment: Ah, I would suggest refactoring it for consistency since you are looking to package it together. That way it's consistent to use `src.foo` or something like `from .. import foo`. Doing it now will save you headaches latter when these code grow. I provided an answer below for how to go about separating things.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm wrong, but I'm fairly sure you can't with the way you structure/package your repo. Python will look in `src` and each `__init__.py` allows for it to be indexed and thus it's consider part of the same package. Plus, there are potential namespace conflicts. What if instead of `foo` you had `csv`? That would break the default `csv` library for python. By specifying `src.foo` it's explicit where `foo` is defined.

The only way I can think is to have your code in two separate repository with `foo` available on PyPI (i.e., `pip install foo`). After adding it to your `requirements.txt` Then you can do something like:

```
import foo
```

in `src/__init__.py`. This would allow for you to have: `src.foo` and `foo`.